# Tire best practices with json/many nested active models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tire

I have a pretty complicated model hierarchy that I want to search.  Basically I have a person, who has a resume and that has a lot of things and I want to return the person who matches my free text search ("army" brings up the people were in the army, searching for "super awesome division" returns the people who are in that division etc.

This is an example of what I have so far (not complete)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certifications, :as => :certificationable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :educations, :as => :educationable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :phones, :as => :phoneable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :emails, :as => :emailable, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :resume, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :division
  belongs_to :employment_status
  belongs_to :user

  mapping do

    indexes :id,      index: :not_analyzed
    indexes :first,   analyzer: 'keyword'
    indexes :middle,  analyzer: 'keyword'
    indexes :last,    analyzer: 'keyword'
    indexes :sector
    indexes :job_title
    indexes :div_title
    indexes :loc
    indexes :department
    indexes :unit
    indexes :unit_name, analyzer: 'snowball'

    indexes :division, :analyzer => 'snowball', :class => [Division], :type => :nested

    indexes :employment_status
    indexes :emails do
      indexes :address 
    end

    indexes :phones do
      indexes :number
    end

    indexes :resume do
      indexes :military_services do
        indexes :military_rank do
          indexes :title
          indexes :abbreviation
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def to_indexed_json
    to_json(
        except: [:avatar],
        include: {
          division: {
            only: [:name, :abbrev, :id]
          },

          emails: {
            only: [:address]
          },

          phones: {
            only: [:number]
          },

          resume: {
           include: {
             military_services: {
               exclude: [:updated_at, :created_at],
               include: {
                 military_rank: {
                   only: [:title, :abbreviation]
                 }
               }
             }
           }
          }
        }
    )
  end

  def self.search(params, options = {})
    tire.search(options) do
      query do
        boolean do
          must { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
          must { term :division_id, params[:division_id] } if params[:division_id].present?
        end
      end

      sort { by :first, 'asc' }

      facet :division do
        terms :division_id
      end
    end
  end
```

end

This seems to work but it's kind of unwieldly because I have to reach pretty deep into some of these models for both the indexing and the json.  Is this the best way to accomplish my goal?  I keep feeling like there must be a way to index and map all of my models and their relations and then relate them back to the Person.

I'm also struggling with the json as it's pretty unwieldly.  Do people use jbuilder or active_model_serializers for this?

Comment: Do you want it to search everything in your mapping? How are you consuming the search results? Also, if you're looking to index each of these models, I just released a gem that might be useful -- [lifesaver](https://github.com/paulnsorensen/lifesaver) -- it requires resque, though.